# Selenium Webdriver with Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver with Ruby. What is the easiest way to test in Internet Explorer, chrome and Firefox at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

```
browse = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

browse2 = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

browse.get "http://google.co.uk"

browse2.get "http://google.co.uk"
```

and respectively for internet explorer. If this isn't what you are looking for I'm not sure you can run tests in different browsers at EXACTLY the same time.